# half-sine pulse shaping

Tags: matlab, communication, signals, signal-processing

i wanted to know what is the pulse shape of the [modem.oqpskmod](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/modem.oqpskmod.html)? and if it is not half-sine pulse shape, how is it possible to make it half-sine pulse shape as it is stated in ieee 802.15.4(zigbee) standard where it shows it as follows

```
    p(t)=sin(pi*t/2*Tc) if 0<=t<=2Tc
    p(t)=0 if otherwise
```

? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the MATLAB modems just output the symbols and that you will need to manually upsample (zero-stuff) the symbols and apply a pulse-shaping filter of your choice to the result to get your baseband signal. There's an example here: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/ug/a1067963807.html#a1068239783b1